# how to defer form definition until end of multistep dialog using react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs

with the below code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as Dialog from '@radix-ui/react-dialog';
import { Cross2Icon } from '@radix-ui/react-icons';
import * as Form from '@radix-ui/react-form';
import './style.css';
import * as z from 'zod';
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';
import { useForm, type UseFormReturn } from "react-hook-form";
import {useState} from 'react'

const DialogDemo = () => {
  const formSchema = z.object({
    email: z.string().min(2, {
      message: 'Email must be at least 2 characters.',
    }),
  });

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema), // <----- I would like this defined deep in the path based on user input
    defaultValues: {
      email: '',
    },
  });
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
  const fetchedItems = [];
  return (
    <Dialog.Root>
      <Dialog.Trigger asChild>
        <button className="Button violet">Add/edit email item</button>
      </Dialog.Trigger>
      <Dialog.Portal>
        <Dialog.Overlay className="DialogOverlay" />
        <Dialog.Content className="DialogContent">
          <header>
            <Dialog.Title className="DialogTitle">Add/edit email item</Dialog.Title>
          </header>
          <Form.Root className="FormRoot" {...form}>
            <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(() => {
              console.log(form)
            })}>
              <Fields form={form} activeStep={activeStep}/>
              <footer
                style={{
                  display: 'flex',
                  marginTop: 25,
                  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                }}
              >
                {activeStep === 1 && <button className="Button" onClick={() => setActiveStep(0)}>Back</button>}
               {activeStep === 1 ? <Dialog.Close asChild>
                  <button className="Button green">Save changes</button>
                </Dialog.Close> : <button className="Button green" onClick={() => setActiveStep(1)}>Next</button> }
              </footer>
              <Dialog.Close asChild>
                <button className="IconButton" aria-label="Close">
                  <Cross2Icon />
                </button>
              </Dialog.Close>
            </form>
          </Form.Root>
        </Dialog.Content>
      </Dialog.Portal>
    </Dialog.Root>
  );
};

export default DialogDemo;

function Fields({form, activeStep}) {
   return activeStep === 0 ? <Form.Field className="FormField" name="email"
                        control={form.control}
              >
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    alignItems: 'baseline',
                    justifyContent: 'space-between',
                  }}
                >
                  <Form.Label className="FormLabel">Email</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Message className="FormMessage" match="valueMissing">
                    Please enter your email
                  </Form.Message>
                  <Form.Message className="FormMessage" match="typeMismatch">
                    Please provide a valid email
                  </Form.Message>
                </div>
                <Form.Control asChild>
                  <input className="Input" type="email" required />
                </Form.Control>
              </Form.Field> : <div>done</div>
}
```

This code works as is since I have a schema defined although ultimately, I'd like the schema to be defined at the very end. This can be solved if I move all the form stuff to the leaf component of this tree but I'd like for the modal component to be reusable and not have to define a footer at every leaf component. Thank you.